# How to run make from Cygwin environment?

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to run linux driver on linux environment .. Following instruction  to run winkvm .. stuck on point run make command using cygwin environment .. 
like

1. Building original KVM drivers using Cygwin environment:

   cd kvm/kernel  ## Do not type configure
   make           ## you will get id: unrecognised emulation mode: elf_i386 but it's not error
   make cpobjs    ## If you get not a directory message, make it and try again

How to run make command .. from which console of cygwin.. 
getting error bash make command not found .. from cygwin terminal

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You have to install the `make` command.

Run the Cygwin installation/configuration program, `setup-x86_64.exe` or `setup-x86.exe` (you should already have it, downloaded from [here](https://www.cygwin.com/install.html)). When you get to the screen that lets you select packages to install, find `make` and select it (it's probably under "Development" or something similar).

Then you'll be able to run `make` from the Cygwin bash command line.

Comment: It is in the package ``make: The GNU version of the 'make' utility``.

Comment: It seems you also need to add the Cygwin bin folder to your Windows path.

Comment: @jciloa: Only if you want to run it from the Windows environment.  You just need to have `/usr/bin` in your Cygwin/bash path.

Answer (score 22):

If you have cygwin running, terminate it. Download the setup-x86_64.exe utility from the cygwin site (https://www.cygwin.com/). Run the utility and continue by clicking "Next" until you get to the window where you can select packages.
[image]

Type into the search panel the word "make". This works like a filter that leaves only packages related to make functionality. In category "Devel" select "make: the GNU version of 'make' utility". That is.