# How to run make from Cygwin 2.918 environment?

Tags: makefile, cygwin

This question was asked 8 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710209/how-to-run-make-from-cygwin-environment), but the result is different today.

Then, the answer was to select make in the installer. Today (following the original steps with the Cygwin 2.918 64 bit installer currently available from [Cygwin.com](http://cygwin.com/install.html)) the option to install make is not present. Searching for make in the Select Packages dialog of the installer finds nothing.

Using the Category View, the Devel category contains only contains libargp and libintl8.

After completing installation, make is not available from the cygwin terminal. Cygwin looks on the Windows path and finds other versions of make.

Here is the view from the Cygwin installer with Category selected:
[image]

View with filter on "make"
[image]

What is the current process to install make and related development tools for Cygwin?

Comment: Go back on "Choose a Download Source" window and select "Install from Internet". The fact that on Devel selection you see only 2 installed packages, tell me that that you selected "Install from Local Directory" and of course you have not make available there

Comment: @matzeri, that was it. The local directory was only populated with "Default" packages and when I re-ran the installer, it retained the selection for local directory.  I changed to Internet and there were over 1200 packages for Devel.  I installed them, and now make is working. I also have 12 GB of new files, so I should probably try to trim them to the essentials.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce. The `make` package shows up just fine, together with a lot of other packages...?!? Double-check that you actually selected the "Category" view, and not the (default) "Pending" view, which shows packages with pending updates.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - that is curious - my installer looks different. See edit of question with image.

Comment: It occurs to me that I might have picked a bad mirror site with incomplete packages. Which one did you use?

Comment: @tim11g: I think matseri's comment ("Install from local directory"?) might be it. I chose a German mirror, which is likely not an ideal choice for you. If the one you chose is bad, just pick another.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin GUI might not work for some reason, you can try command line install :

```
setup-x86_64.exe -q -s https://cygwin.mirror.com -R "C:/Cygwin" -l "C:/CygInstall" -P make
```

You need to put parameters of your system for `-s/-R/-l`